# Dropdown selected value from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Angular newbie question

I have a dropdown showing days from week something like this

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectedDayofWeek" ng-model="selectedDayofWeek" ng-selected="sdw">
                          <option value="">Select</option>
                          <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
                          <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                          <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                          <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
                          <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
                          <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
                          <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
                        </select>
```

In my controller I have

```
$scope.sdw = json[0].DayofWeek; // Thursday
```

However this does not selects the dropdown's Thursday value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `ng-model` specified in your HTML to be of the same name on your `$scope`.

Change `$scope.sdw = json[0].DayofMonth` into

`$scope.selectedDayofWeek = json[0].DayofMonth;`

The `ng-selected` is redundant (and not used well, read about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)).

Comment: I initially tried this (i mean $scope.selectedDayofWeek = json[0].DayofWeek) but it didnt work. So then I googled and found ng-selected thing but that didnt work either. Thanks for your comment. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that `json[0].DayofWeek` contains `Thursday` exactly? it is case sensitive. Anyway, see this fiddle for a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/bjamqfru/1/